# Output matrix field content into a RSS feed

Tags: matrix, rss, xml

I'm trying to create RSS feed for a site news section, most of it is straight forward to do but I run into an issue with the description section. That content is a sub field in a matrix field along with other subfields like downloads and block quotes.

I have looked extensively, and I haven't found any examples or ideas on how to do this. I can output the matrix field itself in the rss and it gives me a list of all the fieldnames it contains but I can't find a way to output those sub fields into the RSS feed as items.
Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by filtering the Matrix field down to just the field block(s) you want using their handle.

```
{% for entry in craft.entries.section('articles').all() %}
    <item>
        <title>{{ entry.title }}</title>
        <link>{{ entry.url }}</link>
        <pubDate>{{ entry.postDate|rss }}</pubDate>
        <author>{{ entry.author }}</author>
        <guid>{{ entry.url }}</guid>
        <description><![CDATA[
        {% for block in entry.myMatrixField.type('blockTypeHandle').all() %}
             {{ block.textContent|striptags }}
        {% endfor %}
        ]]></description>
    </item>
{% endfor %}
```

This example filters a Matrix field down to just the blocks that have a handle of `blockTypeHandle` within the field, and outputs their content, which in this case is a rich text field with a handle of `textContent`.

Comment: Hi Martin , your code makes sense but it doesn't work for me . My matrix field is called innerContent , my block is called innerText and my field is called text . Here is the code I used <description><![CDATA[  {% for block in entry.innerContent.type('innerText').all() %}
                                {{ block.text|striptags }}
                                {% endfor %}
]]></description>. I get a Twig error Variable "entry" does not exist. I have wrapped the code in with the right craft entries tag as the rss outputs correctly if I leave out that matrix block.

Comment: Hmm, that's odd. Is there an `entry` variable available within the `{% for .. in %}` loop? What do you get if you add a `{% dd entry %}` statement inside the loop?

Comment: Thanks Martin, got it working. I was using item instead of entry to define the Rss fields. Thanks for your help